# Bug with table cdk and mat-tabs-group

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a problem with angular material table.
I have made a table and implement sort, paginator , mat-tabs-group and expandable row.
But when I first , display at least 10 elements and I sort by name, the bug appear,
the row expand itself.

When it's in the mat-tabs, I have this problem, but outside not.
I think it's a problem with table cdk and mat-tabs-group.

I had a Gif to see the bug

I paste  a part of my HTML & Ts here :

```
........


  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private lightService: LightService, public dialog: MatDialog) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    this.lightService.getLamp()
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.lampData = response;
          this.dataSource.data = response;

        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('error ' + error);
        }
      );
  }

 .....
```

HTML

```
......


      <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
          <div class="example-element-detail" *ngIf="element.error"
               [@detailExpand]="element === expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
            <div>
              <p>serial : <strong>{{element.serial}} </strong></p>
              <p> {{element.name}} have a problem.</p>
              <p  (click)="openDialog()" class="technician">Error message</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"
          class="example-element-row"
          [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row" ></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This is bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR1ds.gif)

Comment: Would you be able to provide https://stackblitz.com/ link for the same?

Comment: I had a gif for view the problem

Comment: I ran into this problem few weeks back, but couldn't recollect it now. do you have a stackblitz that we can look at?

Comment: I try to make it with starblitz but at the end I have an error : can't find the https: package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer in this post on Github

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13835

It's just about setting good the animations is TS file.